# Erro installing cordova ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm a beginner in ionic and I want to install it and I got some problems

I tried

```
  npm install ionic -g cordova
```

I got

```
npm WARN deprecated superagent@4.1.0: Please note that v5.0.1+ of 
superagent removes User-Agent header by default, there
fore you may need to add it yourself (e.g. GitHub blocks requests without 
a User-Agent header).  This notice will go awa
y with v5.0.2+ once it is released.
C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> 
C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> 
C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
+ ionic@5.2.4
+ cordova@9.0.0
updated 2 packages in 117.964s
```

I configured the proxy to localhost:8888
but when I tried to start and app I got

```
   V Preparing directory .\myApp - done!
   \ Downloading and extracting tabs starter
   [ERROR] Network connectivity error occurred, are you offline?

    If you are behind a firewall and need to configure proxy settings, 
    see: https://ion.link/cli-proxy-docs

    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
   / Downloading and extracting tabs starter
    Terminer le programme de commandes (O/N) ? o
```

It stay like this for a long time without any progresse,I'l using 32bits windows 7 and I installed nodjs and npm

Comment: Can you do the following command? `ionic -v`

Comment: it's say 5.2.4 which mean that it's installed

Comment: And can you generate a new project?

Comment: no it's say                 [ERROR] Network connectivity error occurred, are you offline?

    If you are behind a firewall and need to configure proxy settings, 
    see: https://ion.link/cli-proxy-docs

    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
   / Downloading and extracting tabs starter                                                                         and it's stay like this without any progresse

Comment: Are you using a home network or company?

Comment: I'm using home network

Comment: I suggest to do a hard reset on your modem/router and try again.

Comment: I tried in two diffrent days I even turned off the pc and router

Comment: Can you try delete everything and install in following order:

1. Install NodeJS
2. Install Cordova
3. Install the android SDK

Comment: Thank you I will try it

Comment: It didin't work same problem

Comment: Then I think something is mess up with windows.. Make a backup from your files and do a clean install via USB.